# How to create input type text dynamically in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know in javascript, I can create an element in below way.

```
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     input.type = "text";
     input.className = "css-class-name"; // set the CSS class
     document.body.appendChild(input);
```

In my angular application, I'm getting some array value from http service inside `ngOnInit` of app.component.ts.

I have a scenario to create the input type text dynamically  based on array value. If the array value is 5, it should create five input type.

Is it possible with typescript? Or should I use the above code in typescript as well?

What is the best approach to deal this scenario?

Comment: You mean if length of array is five?

Comment: Yes Exactly.....

Comment: TypeScript compiles to, and is a superset of, JavaScript. Anything you write in JavaScript will be valid TypeScript. However, in Angular it's not a good idea to create nodes using `createElement` and the like. You probably want to create an array of 5 elements, and bind an `*ngFor` to that.

Comment: Your code already is valid Typescript except you haven't added types.

Comment: @connexo true, though it's not recommended in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a bundle of form controls. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b5q4c4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```js
inputs: FormControl[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getNumberOfInputs().subscribe(count => {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      this.inputs.push(new FormControl(''));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" *ngFor="let input of inputs" [formControl]="input">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*ngFor`, which is an Angular directive, to loop over elements of the array.
If in your model you have `public array = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, and in your template you have

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let element of array">{{ element }}</li>
</ul>
```

this will print the following DOM:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

So, for your problem, to create inputs, just put inputs inside the loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let element of array">
  <input type="text" class="css-class-name">
</div>
```

By the way, this is a basic operation in Angular templates. 
I urge you to [read the official introduction to Angular](https://angular.io/tutorial) from the official site to get a grasp at what Angular can do.

Answer (score 1):

**Component:**

```
public inputControlsArr : Array<any> = [];

this.service.getValues().subscribe((values)=>{
   this.inputControlsArr = values;
});
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let input of inputControlsArr; let i = index;">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)}="inputControlsArr[i]"/>
</div>
```